# Do I have to sanitize the AJAX response data?

Tags: php, ajax

I have searched the net for this but got nowhere.

I am using AJAX to post a form to **process.php** which will validate and sanitize the posted data, if successful it will echo a string **"success"** through AJAX response. Do I have to sanitize and escape  the string **"success"** before I output it to the user?
 Knowing that the string **"success"** is not a user input and is just a string written by me to indicted successful process.

Do I have to sanitize and escape any AJAX response data even that it is created by me? 
This is because in other pages I echo a lot of HTML elements directly from processing php page, so I can get them in the AJAX response and use innerHTML to output them to the user directly without filtering.

Thank you

Comment: No sense in sanitizing there, _if_ you already take care what you post on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already validated and sanitized the POST-ed data, there is no need to run a second step through the AJAX response. I echo a a lot of HTML elements too, and directly echo it straight. You need to validate that your AJAX is not vulnerable to XSS via user-input. However, if you were to 'accidentally' include a script in your own string, then that would be an issue.